# Return first vertical value that matches given criterion

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

On Google Sheets, I would like to figure out a way to have a cell return the first value in column C where the same row in column D matches the criterion ("Blue" for example, as opposed to "Red"). I only need the value that is vertically the highest in column C whose row fits the criterion, since the column is already sorted. Additionally, I will be using this formula on a given sheet (ex. "Sheet A") but referring to data from another sheet which contains the criteria ("Sheet B" for example). Sorry, I'm a bit new to arrays and/or complicated formulae in Sheets.

Comment: Welcome. It's expected that question authors share a brief description of their search/research efforts. Please checkout [ask].

Comment: Okay thanks for the heads up, I'll do that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **for numbers:**

  ```
  =QUERY(C:D, "select C where D = 5 limit 1", 0)
  ```

  [image]
- **for text:**

  ```
  =QUERY(C:D, "select C where D = 'red' limit 1", 0)
  ```

  [image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! This solved my problem.

Comment: Why not `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: @oshliaer could be too... like 2-3 other different ways. I didn't choose `VLOOKUP` coz it would require flipping columns eg `QUERY` is more pleasant to the eye in this scenario

Comment: I think `limit 1` does the work fine. Thanks